# How to pass variables from a py2exe'd python program to a function in another python script

Tags: python, py2exe, argument-passing

I have two modules:  `reader.py`  and `processor.py`. The `reader.py` reads an XML configuration file, validates it, and stores its values in an object. It then calls the `processor.py` and passes the object to it.

The project requirements state that `reader` must be compiled to executable. I do this using py2exe. Now that `reader` is an executable, how can it pass values to `processor`? When they were both scripts it would be as simple as

```
from processor import myFunc
myFunc(myArgs)
```

but now that `reader` is an executable I launch `processor` by

```
subprocess.call([“python”, “processor.py”])
```

How can I pass it the object with the variables red from the xml file? I don’t want to do it all as a string, because re-parsing the string would defeat the purpose of `reader`

Comment: Pickle the object and pass the pickle file name to the second process which can read an un-pickle the data.

Comment: @martineau generally speaking is un-pickling faster than rereading (and parsing) an XML configuration file? I ask because if a file is being red then it sort of seems like redoing the same work which was just done, which was reading the values from a file into variables. Hopefully I'm being clear in what I'm saying.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure it would be faster than parsing XML. However, there may be issues with using pickle in an .exe, since it uses Python source files to get definitions from when unpickling (if you're trying to unpickle instances of user-defined classes as opposed to built-ins).

Comment: Why don't you just import `processor` like before?

Comment: @BlackJack it says `ImportError: No module named 'processor'` even though I have the exe and processor.py in same folder

Comment: The `exe` changes the working directory so you'll have to add the path to the `exe` to `sys.path`.

Comment: @BlackJack not sure I follow. Do you mean add the `exe`s path to the `sys.path` in the .py script?

Comment: Yes, then importing modules from that path should be possible.